# How to design a generic class in Java which can check allowed values supplied to it?

Tags: java, class, generics, collections

I am trying to design an interface which has a method that checks if the supplied values are present in the class implementing the interface which hold the data structure too.

Here I want to give the flexibility to implementer to encompass any type of collection.

Below is the code:

```
public interface AllowedValues<T>{

//T represents the type of values the implementing class will hold.
public boolean exits(T t)

}
```

Now I want the implementing class to hold the collection. which would be looped through to check if the parameter passes to exists() function is present in the collection

```
public class AllowedValue implements AllowedValues<String>{

List<String> listOfAllowedvalues; // I want to make this collection to be generic.

public boolean exist(String s){

return listOfAllowedValues.contains(s);

    }
}
```

How can I add the flexibility in the interface even to make the choice of collection to be generic?

Comment: This questions appears to be unclear to me, can you try to rephrase what you **actually** want? With for example an input/output scheme, or allowed vs not-allowed scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do:

```
public class AllowedValue<T> implements AllowedValues<T>
{
  private Collection<T> allowedvalues;

  public AllowedValue(Collection<T> allowedvalues)
  {
    this.allowedvalues = allowedvalues; 
  }

  @Override
  public boolean exist(T value)
  {
    return listOfAllowedValues.contains(value);
  }
}
```

You'd then create an `AllowedValue` like this:

```
Collection<String> allowedStrings = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World"); 

AllowedValues<String> allowedValues = new AllowedValue<>(allowedStrings);

assert(allowedValues.exist("Hello"));
assert(!allowedValues.exist("Universe"));
```

Comment: Can I also make the List, Map, Set as Type parameters of the interface so that even the choice of collection will also be generic.

Comment: Yes (for `List` or `Set`, but `Map` isn't a `Collection` and doesn't have a `contains` method), but that's uneccessary - the `contains` method is defined on `Collection` so putting a generic in for the type doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: Why is it necessary to declare Type parameter T on implementing class i.e. AllowedValue and the interface AllowedValues, when you already have a Type parameter on AllowedValues?

Comment: The type parameter is passed from `AllowedValue` to `AllowedValues` and should be specified when creating an instance of `AllowedValue` - I'll add a code example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `List<String> listOfAllowedvalues` do `List<T> listOfAllowedvalues`.

```
public class AllowedValue<T> implements AllowedValues<T>{

    List<T> listOfAllowedvalues; // I want to make this collection to be generic.

    public boolean exist(T s){

       return listOfAllowedValues.contains(s);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Collection interface instead of the List one because Collection has the contains() method.

Answer (score 0):

Insn't this what you want?

```
public class AllowedValue<T> {

    public AllowedValue(List<T> allowed){
        listOfAllowedvalues.addAll(allowed);
    }
    List<T> listOfAllowedvalues;

    public boolean exist(T s) {
        return listOfAllowedvalues.contains(s);
    }

}
```